# Does react native has similar require methods such as require.context?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to write React Native code in ts, one of them is that i want import page direction  and use a request method (such as require.context) to analysis all page info instead of just import pages path. So how can i do this? Does RN support it?

Answer (score 1):

I find someone had resolved this issue. Just use `babel-plugin-import-glob`. Then your can use it that the same as use `require.context`, we can do this:

```
import * as batch from "../foo/*.js"
```

Links: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15508